# Cloud run deployment failed - Container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8001

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, uvicorn

I keep getting this error when trying to deploy my docker container on cloudrun:

```
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8001 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

[image]

Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8001"]
```

How I run my server:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8001, reload=True)
```

I have no idea why it's not working. I've deployed similar servers in the past with very similar configurations. Anyone know?

Comment: Did you go to the Cloud Logging to have more details? The error simply said that the container failed to start and therefore the port 8001 is not open. Go to the log you will see WHY it did not start.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue... 
Main takeaway here is, test locally first https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#gcloud-cli
I tried running the image locally, grabbing the image from GCR and it ended up being an import errors (I had a leftover import that I forgot to delete in my code)

Comment: The problem will be logged in Cloud Logging. Those logs are available in the Google Cloud web GUI and from the command line. Example CLI: `gcloud beta run services logs read CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME --limit=25 --project PROJECT_ID`. I put that command into a batch file and run it after each deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that will encounter this kind of issue.

According to @Daichi

> Managed to fix the issue... Main takeaway here is, test locally first I tried running the image locally, grabbing the image from GCR and it ended up being an import errors (I had a leftover import that I forgot to delete in my code)

---

For more information about Cloud Run service locally, you may visit this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#gcloud-cli).